# Check if pagination in header

Tags: pagination

guys.

I'm a beginner to EE and I'm looking for a way to add "" to any paginated pages in a Blog template in EE.

Is there any way to check in header if it's a paginated page and, if so, display this tag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you don't want to lock your code to a specific segment and also for better performance comparing existing variables is better than running a regular expression.

My best recommendation, albeit a bit overkill just for this one conditional is to use the brilliant [Mo' Variables](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables) plug-in, mainly because it adds loads more variables that are really useful to your build and obviouly make your code more readable...

```
{if paginated}
    ...
{/if}
```

Assuming you have a page of content (entry_id) for the listing page, you could use this comparison:

```
{if url_title == last_segment}
   {!-- This is the first page (not pagination) --}
{if:else}
   {!-- This is a paginated page --}
{/if}
```

If the page only contains listed entry_id's, you could use this [conditional](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/conditionals.html#comparison-operators):

```
{if last_segment ^= "P"}
   {!-- This is a paginated page --}
{/if}
```

...Although this assumes that the template used hasn't got a segment already that starts with a capital P!

Checking for any above page one (obviously this only works inside the `{paginate}` tag pair)...

```
{if current_page > 1}
    ...
{/if}
```

The [official documentation](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/conditionals.html#matches-operator) suggests this:

```
{if segment_3 ~ "/^P\d+/"}paginated{/if}
```

But I'd try to opt for this version instead:

```
{if last_segment ~ "/^P\d+/"}paginated{/if}
```